# Sum the values in object by quarter system

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the sum of totals based on quarter system.

```
data= [{
    "rowLabel": "Label",
    "previousYearSpend": "21239481.8",
    "janActual": "13146105.51",
    "janPlan": "13126631.26",
    "febActual": "129458614.21",
    "febPlan": "12440428.3",
    "marActual": "15269255.37",
    "marPlan": "1497070.55",
    "aprActual": "16996329.67",
    "aprPlan": "15683061.15",
    "mayActual": "13736166.96",
    "mayPlan": "14847570.78",
    "junActual": "135525666.19",
    "junPlan": "14849827.86",
    "julActual": "",
    "julPlan": "15908197.25",
    "augActual": "",
    "augPlan": "",
    "sepActual": "",
    "sepPlan": "",
    "octActual": "",
    "octPlan": "",
    "novActual": "",
    "novPlan": "",
    "decActual": "",
    "decPlan": ""
}]
```

The result I am looking for is

```
    "marActual": "15269255.37",
    "marPlan": "1497070.55",
    "aprActual": "16996329.67",
    "aprPlan": "15683061.15",
    "mayActual": "13736166.96",
    "mayPlan": "14847570.78",
    "junActual": "135525666.19",
    "junPlan": "14849827.86",
    "julActual": "",
    "julPlan": "15908197.25"
```

where `marActual = janActual+febActual+marActual`
`marPlan = janPlan+febPlan+marPlan`

I pass the date as 
`'2015/JUN/01'` , result should be `Q1, APR, MAY, JUN`
if I pass the date as `'2015/JUL/1'` it should be `Q1, Q2, JUL`
where `junActual = aprActual+mayActual+junActual`
and `junPlan = aprPlan+mayPlan+junPlan`

I am confused with the logic I have to sum the values [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dd0pwtoL/1/).
My datatable is built on this data, it dynamically creates the table and renders the table with this json.

Comment: You say you want to have returned `Q1, APR, MAY, JUN` and `Q1, Q2, JUL`, but exactly what values do they represent? What are the expected values for (e.g.) `Q1` and `JUL`?

Comment: @FDekker `Q1` is `marActual` and `marPlan` in the table, so `marActual(Q1Actual)=janActual+febActual+marActual`
`marPlan(Q1Plan)=janPlan+febPlan+marPlan`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, but it is kind of clunky :/ I will see if I can clean this up some.

```
data= [{
    "rowLabel": "Label",
    "previousYearSpend": "21239481.8",
    "janActual": "13146105.51",
    "janPlan": "13126631.26",
    "febActual": "129458614.21",
    "febPlan": "12440428.3",
    "marActual": "15269255.37",
    "marPlan": "1497070.55",
    "aprActual": "16996329.67",
    "aprPlan": "15683061.15",
    "mayActual": "13736166.96",
    "mayPlan": "14847570.78",
    "junActual": "135525666.19",
    "junPlan": "14849827.86",
    "julActual": "",
    "julPlan": "15908197.25",
    "augActual": "",
    "augPlan": "",
    "sepActual": "",
    "sepPlan": "",
    "octActual": "",
    "octPlan": "",
    "novActual": "",
    "novPlan": "",
    "decActual": "",
    "decPlan": ""
    }];

quarterActual = function(){
    monthsCorrect = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']; //store months in correct order

    Q1 = monthsCorrect.slice(0,3);
    Q2 = monthsCorrect.slice(3,6);
    Q3 = monthsCorrect.slice(6,9);
    Q4 = monthsCorrect.slice(9,12);

    totaQ1 = 0;
    totaQ2 = 0;
    totaQ3 = 0;
    totaQ4 = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < Q1.length; k++) {
        a1 = Q1[k] + 'Actual';
        a2 = Q2[k] + 'Actual';
        a3 = Q3[k] + 'Actual';
        a4 = Q4[k] + 'Actual';

        totaQ1 += Number(data[0][a1]);
        totaQ2 += Number(data[0][a2]);
        totaQ3 += Number(data[0][a3]);
        totaQ4 += Number(data[0][a4]);

    }
    return([String(totaQ1), String(totaQ2), String(totaQ3), String(totaQ4)]);

}

quarterPlan = function() {
    monthsCorrect = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']; //store months in correct order

    Q1 = monthsCorrect.slice(0,3);
    Q2 = monthsCorrect.slice(3,6);
    Q3 = monthsCorrect.slice(6,9);
    Q4 = monthsCorrect.slice(9,12);

    totpQ1 = 0;
    totpQ2 = 0;
    totpQ3 = 0;
    totpQ4 = 0;

    for (var k = 0; k < Q1.length; k++) {
        p1 = Q1[k] + 'Plan';
        p2 = Q2[k] + 'Plan';
        p3 = Q3[k] + 'Plan';
        p4 = Q4[k] + 'Plan';

        totpQ1 += Number(data[0][p1]);
        totpQ2 += Number(data[0][p2]);
        totpQ3 += Number(data[0][p3]);
        totpQ4 += Number(data[0][p4]);
    }
    return([String(totpQ1), String(totpQ2), String(totpQ3), String(totpQ4)]);
}


quarterlyReport = function(date){ // date can be in your format, '2015/JUN/01', or even just the abbreviation
    date = date.toLowerCase();
    monthsCorrect = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']; //store months in correct order
    quarterReport = {}; // the quarter report
    // find which month to stop at using regular expression
    for (i = 0; i < monthsCorrect.length; i++){
        var monRegEx = RegExp(monthsCorrect[i]);
        var test = monRegEx.test(date);
        if (test == true){break;}
    }
    var monthStop = i; //index that for loop above stopped at
    included = monthsCorrect.slice(0,monthStop + 1); // months to report back

    if(included.length == 3){
        quarterReport.Q1Actual = quarterActual()[0];
        quarterReport.Q1Plan = quarterPlan()[0];

        } else if (included.length > 3 && included.length <= 6){
        quarterReport.Q1Actual = quarterActual()[0];
        quarterReport.Q1Plan = quarterPlan()[0];
        // report months after Q1
        monthsAfter = monthsCorrect.slice(Q1.length, included.length)
        for (m = 0; m < monthsAfter.length; m++){
            act = monthsAfter[m] + 'Actual';
            pl = monthsAfter[m] + 'Plan';
            quarterReport[act] = data[0][act];
            quarterReport[pl] = data[0][pl];
        }

        }  else if (included.length > 6 && included.length <= 9){
            quarterReport.Q1Actual = quarterActual()[0];
            quarterReport.Q1Plan = quarterPlan()[0];
            quarterReport.Q2Actual = quarterActual()[1];
            quarterReport.Q2Plan = quarterPlan()[1];

            monthsAfter = monthsCorrect.slice(Q1.length*2, included.length)
            for (n = 0; n < monthsAfter.length; n++){
                act = monthsAfter[n] + 'Actual';
                pl = monthsAfter[n] + 'Plan';
                quarterReport[act] = data[0][act];
                quarterReport[pl] = data[0][pl];
            }

        } else if (included.length > 9 && included.length <= 12){
            quarterReport.Q1Actual = quarterActual()[0];
            quarterReport.Q1Plan = quarterPlan()[0];
            quarterReport.Q2Actual = quarterActual()[1];
            quarterReport.Q2Plan = quarterPlan()[1];
            quarterReport.Q3Actual = quarterActual()[2];
            quarterReport.Q3Plan = quarterPlan()[2];

            monthsAfter = monthsCorrect.slice(Q1.length*3, included.length)
            for (n = 0; n < monthsAfter.length; n++){
                act = monthsAfter[n] + 'Actual';
                pl = monthsAfter[n] + 'Plan';
                quarterReport[act] = data[0][act];
                quarterReport[pl] = data[0][pl];
            }

        } else {
            for(var j = 0; j < included.length; j++){
                actual = included[j] + 'Actual';
                plan = included[j] + 'Plan';
                quarterReport[actual] = data[0][actual];
                quarterReport[plan] = data[0][plan];
            }
        }

    return(quarterReport);

}
console.log(quarterlyReport('2015/JUN/01'));
```

For June, this returns:

```
{Q1Actual: "157873975.09" 
Q1Plan:"27064130.110000003"
aprActual:"16996329.67"
aprPlan:"15683061.15"  
junActual:"135525666.19" 
junPlan:"14849827.86" 
mayActual: "13736166.96"       
mayPlan: "14847570.78"}
```

Btw I ran your script and if March is supposed to return the cumulative total, then I think your amount is wrong for the `Q1actual`(`marActual`). I added up Jan, Feb, and Mar and ended up with the total I have for `Q1Actual.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with, if there is a better solution than mine, i will use that code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dd0pwtoL/2/)

```
var aMonths = ["jan", "feb", "mar",
               "apr", "may", "jun",
               "jul", "aug", "sep",
               "oct", "nov", "dec"],
    data= [{
    "rowLabel": "Label",
    "previousYearSpend": "21239481.8",
    "janActual": "13146105.51",
    "janPlan": "13126631.26",
    "febActual": "12958614.21",
    "febPlan": "12440428.3",
    "marActual": "15269255.37",
    "marPlan": "1497070.55",
    "aprActual": "16996329.67",
    "aprPlan": "15683061.15",
    "mayActual": "13736166.96",
    "mayPlan": "14847570.78",
    "junActual": "135525666.19",
    "junPlan": "14849827.86",
    "julActual": "",
    "julPlan": "15908197.25",
    "augActual": "",
    "augPlan": "",
    "sepActual": "",
    "sepPlan": "",
    "octActual": "",
    "octPlan": "",
    "novActual": "",
    "novPlan": "",
    "decActual": "",
    "decPlan": ""
}];

console.log(sumByQuarter('2015/APR/01',  data, aMonths));

function sumByQuarter(date, data, aMonths) {
    //console.log(data);
    var today = new Date(date) || new Date(),
        QUARTER = 3,
        month = today.getMonth(),
        limit = (month > aMonths.length) ? aMonths.length : month,
        aData = [],
        tempMonths = aMonths.slice(),
        sumActual = 0;
        sumPlan = 0;
    tempMonths.splice(limit + 1, Number.MAX_VALUE);

    var aQuarter = []; // quater array
    var sumjson = {};
    for(i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        sumActual += parseFloat(data[0][tempMonths[i]+'Actual']);
        sumPlan += parseFloat(data[0][tempMonths[i]+'Plan']);
        if((i+1) % QUARTER == 0 ) {
            sumjson[tempMonths[i]+'Actual'] = sumActual;
            sumjson[tempMonths[i]+'Plan'] = sumPlan;
            aQuarter.push(tempMonths[i]);
            sumActual = 0;
            sumPlan = 0;
        }
    }
    console.log(sumjson);
    var usedElements = aQuarter.length * QUARTER;
    if(tempMonths.length > usedElements) {
        aQuarter = aQuarter.concat(tempMonths.slice(usedElements));        
    }
    //console.log(aQuarter);
    for(j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        var json = {};
        for(i = 0; i < aQuarter.length; i++) {
            json['rowLabel'] = data[j]['rowLabel'];
            json['previousYearSpend'] = data[j]['previousYearSpend'];         
            json[aQuarter[i]+'Actual'] = typeof sumjson[aQuarter[i] + 'Actual'] != 'undefined' ? sumjson[aQuarter[i] + 'Actual'] : data[j][aQuarter[i] + 'Actual'];
            json[aQuarter[i]+'Plan'] = typeof sumjson[aQuarter[i] + 'Plan'] != 'undefined' ? sumjson[aQuarter[i] + 'Plan'] : data[j][aQuarter[i] + 'Plan'];
        }
        aData.push(json);
    }
    //console.log(aData);
    return aData;
}
```